# React. Не обновляется Dom при изменении состояния

Tags: reactjs, forms, setstate, ref

Есть форма с полем "добавить новую категорию" и "выбрать существующую" - тег "select". Через форму добавляю новую категорию. После добавления загружаю список всех категорий и изменяю состояние.

```
async loadCategories() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/product/getCategories');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ categories: data });
}
```

Сбрасываю поля формы и если поле newCategory не пустое меняю состояние newSelectOption

```
resetForm() {                  
    let newCat = this.newCategory.current.value;
    if (newCat != "") {
        this.loadCategories();
        this.setState({ newSelectOption: newCat });
        this.newCategory.current.value = "";
    }
 
    this.setState({ checkAddNewCat: false });
    this.setState({ errors: null });       
    this.setState({ file: [] });
    this.name.current.value = '';
    this.description.current.value = "";
    this.price.current.value = "";    
    this.fileInput.current.value = "";        
}
```

и задаю его defaultValue для тега

```
                    <label>
                    Категория:<br />
                    {errors ? <Error field="ThisCategory" errors={this.state.errors} /> : null}
                    {!this.state.checkAddNewCat && this.state.categories.length > 0 ?
                        <select
                            className="select-category"
                            defaultValue={this.state.newSelectOption}
                            ref={this.thisCategory}
                            >
                            {this.state.categories.map(el => (
                                <option key={el.id} value={el.name}>{el.name}</option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                        : <span></span>
                    }           
                    
                    <div>
                        {errors ? <Error field="NewCategory" errors={this.state.errors} /> : null}
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="создать категорию"
                            onChange={this.handleNewCategory}
                            ref={this.newCategory}/>
                    </div>                    
                </label>
```

но тег "select" остаётся на последнем значении которое было выбрано, а нужно что бы по умолчанию оно выбрало новое добавленное значение категории.

Кстати если в состояние newSelectOption подставить старое значение то все работает оно его выбирает после отправки формы, а новое значение которое было добавлено нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо указать новое добавление значение которое выбрал пользователь в select

```
<select id="exanple">
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected="selected">b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Так получается вы просто отрисовывайте по порядку всегда